# Does "WL.App.copyToClipboard(<param>)" supports Internationalization?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Does "WL.App.copyToClipboard()" supports Internationalization ?
On Android when we copy to clipboard, it shows the pop-up message of "Your text is successfully copied". 
It is fine when the device language is English. But on devices with language set as French, it does not display French translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WL.App.copyToClipboard`'s `toast` pop-up is available in English only. And IMO even the English string is not properly written.

If you are an IBM customer or business partner you can open a PMR and receive an iFix.
I will log a defect.